# why don't we always use the latest .net framework?

Tags: asp.net, .net, frameworks, .net-framework-version

I am very new to DOT.net frameworks. 
Shouldn't we always update to the latest release?
List Entity framework or identity framework .. all those frameworks ... why do we keep them around? just use the latest ones.

In fact, I am just starting to develop an asp.net website with RestAPIs, login, register, social login... 
I wonder what is the best framework version (4.5) to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a large company point of view. You can not always technically get the latest version of .NET on your servers that store your applications. For some you have to go through a series of procedures to get everything to the latest so it's not necessarily developers that can trudge through this when you have a separation of duties like developers, system admins, etc. Although it's highly suggested to use the latest and greatest. Every dev/company has their own way of actually getting the most up-to-date versions of pretty much anything.

Comment: Thanks, So if I am starting from scratch, and I am developing all on my own, I should use the latest ?

Comment: @JooJoo1020 It depends on where you're deploying to. If the server you're deploying to has the latest framework version, then you can target that.

Comment: @JooJoo1020 Not everyone immediately updates to the latest version of .NET as soon as it comes out, but I assure you the repercussions of sticking to 4.5 as opposed to the latest won't hurt anything. Also, what mason said is a great point.

Comment: @mason thanks!! and IS IT TRUE, the newer the framework is, the slower it becomes due to the hardware it needs and features added???

Comment: @JooJoo1020 No. Generally additional features don't take more time. They're just there, you don't have to use them. And newer versions can have performance improvements.

Comment: @mason Cool Thanks... I am new to this. Why did my question get -5?

Comment: Most users will down vote questions if it hits a certain criteria that can create more or less arguments and debates. Kind of like this example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544903/i-want-to-learn-game-development-which-language-should-i-use)